# Javascript/Jquery Boolean help: Hiding/Showing Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, boolean, hide, show

Can someone explain to me what i am doing wrong in this code?

http://jsfiddle.net/14njfqef/

```
var isLoggedIn = function(state){
        if(state == true) {
            $("#content-container").show();
            $("#account2").show();
            $("#account").hide();
        }
        else(state == false){
            $("#content-container").hide();
            $("#account2").hide();
            $("#account").show();
        }
    }

onload=function() {
            isLoggedIn(false);
    }
```

On load i want the divs to hide but then when i click the button i want the divs to show?

Is the boolean function set out in the correct way?

Comment: *"Is the boolean function set out in the correct way?"* No: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { `. Learn more about `if...else` statements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Comment: `else if`, not just `else` or just drop the condition part for the else part, but your fiddle is also setup wrong as your js code is loaded in an onload event already

Comment: What `@Patrick Evans` said, and you would put all of your JavaScript inside of your `onload = function(){/* in here */}`. The jQuery `onload` equivalent looks like `$(function(){/* in here */})`, in it's simplest form.

Comment: So turns out the only thing that was wrong was that i was using "==" instead of "==="

Answer (score 1):

Piece below tries to re-arrange piece at OP. `onload` not appear clearly defined , not addressed , though could be attached to an `event` , i.e.g., `window.onload = onload` . Wrapped blocks in jquery `.ready()` `event` . Removed `js` `onclick` markup from `html` , included at `script` element , or loaded from file at jquery `.on("click")` event . Added strict comparison operator `===` (an added `=`) to `if` / `else if` statements. Changed `input` `type` to button. Added `if` to `else` portion of composition (see link posted at comments by Felix Kling).

Try

```
$(function() {
var isLoggedIn = function(state){
        if(state === true) {
            $("#content-container").show();
            $("#account2").show();
            $("#account").hide();
        }
        else if(state === false){
            $("#content-container").hide();
            $("#account2").hide();
            $("#account").show();
        }
    };

    isLoggedIn(false);

    $("input[type=button]").click(function() {
      isLoggedIn(true)
    })
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/14njfqef/3/

Comment: Of course, `isLoggedIn` should be executed after an AJAX response.

Comment: Why should the OP try this? What's the problem with their code? How does your solution solve it?

Comment: @LearnerBeware Not certain what _"the other javascript functions"_ are ? If possible, can include `js` , `html` at OP / jsfiddle ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have JQuery library loaded. Try

```
if (state) {
        $("#content-container").show();
        $("#account2").show();
        $("#account").hide();

}
else{

     $("#content-container").hide();
        $("#account2").hide();
        $("#account").show();
}
```

to solve your problem.

Comment: Why should the OP try this?

Answer (score 0):

changed your html to

```
<input type="submit" value="Boolean" id="toggle"/>
```

rewrote your js as

```
// JQuery run at start effectivly
$(document).ready(function() {

    function isLoggedIn(state) {
        if(state == true) {

            $("#content-container").show();
            $("#account2").show();
            $("#account").hide();
        }
        else {

            $("#content-container").hide();
            $("#account2").hide();
            $("#account").show();
        }
    }

    // JQuery attaching a click event using an anonymous function 
    // and hard coding your isLoggedIn to true, passing variables is a bit more complicated.
    $('#toggle').click(function() {isLoggedIn(true)});

    isLoggedIn(false);
})
```

Comment: `isLoggedIn` should not be executed before the form is submitted. How do you check against the database like that? Use AJAX. `return false;` in your click Event handling function, if you're using a `submit` button with AJAX. Personally, I wouldn't even use a form unless I was going to use `formElement.serialize()` or `formElement.serializeArray()`.

Comment: Why should the HTML and JS be changed? What's the problem?

Comment: This was just a scnippet of the code, which has been simplified to make it easier to answer. This is called once the form has been submitted and the validation comes back correct

Comment: The html was to detach the onclick and make it simpler to attach the event. You could use any kind of selector instead of by id in which case you would just remove the onclick. The reason for removing the onclick is best practices, short version is it leads to cleaner code since all your javascript and events can be centralized. $(document).ready is standard procedure in jquery since it wraps a bunch of dom ready detection. I used a function instead of a variable out of personal preference. The other advantage of wrapping everything in $(document).ready is keeping the window object clean.

Answer (score 0):

Well there's a few things I am not sure if you are aware of so I feel there's some responsibility on my end to make sure they are mentioned. They are a number of syntactical errors in your post that are stopping this from working so instead of addressing them I feel its necessary to update your view on what JQuery you are using as well as your selector choice.

First I would add a class structure to all of the div's to target them all at once so you can save on some lines of code. In production it's always better to have less code for all of your visitors to download because even a little bit of code can get out of control after enough hits on a webpage. Having to serve it kills speed and so does having to process three separate jquery selections as opposed to one.

I would change the HTML to...

```
<body>
    <div id='content-container' class='boxes'>
        Content Container
    </div>
    <div id='account' class='boxes'>
        account
    </div>
    <div id='account2' class='boxes'>
        account2
    </div>
    <input id="validateButton" type="submit" value="Boolean">
</body>
```

This way you can simply target all divs with `$(".boxes");` ... I wouldn't recommend getting into the habbit of using `$("div");`

Next I would change the JQuery to being more JQuery friendly code. Its not always useful to use an `onload` event from pure Javascript to handle JQuery driven functions in correct time to the loading of DOM objects. Therefore you should use `$( document ).ready( handler )` to handle this load event properly just in case it causes you problems down the road. The more common shorthand of this ready event is a simple `$(function() {  });` wrapper.

The rest of the code can be re-arranged to this....

```
var isLoggedIn = false; //<--Instantiate to false, make global to window level scope

//Load event Corrected For JQuery
$(function() {
    $(".boxes").hide(); //<--Hide on load

    //Add A Proper Updated Click Event To Button
    $("#validateButton").click(function() {
        isLoggedIn = true; //<--Should include real functionality not hand coded to true
        checkLoginAndRespond(); //<--Validate Login Status
    });
});

function checkLoginAndRespond() {
    //If Logged, Show
    if(isLoggedIn) {
        $(".boxes").show();

    //Else Don't
    } else { $(".boxes").hide(); }

} //end function
```

Lastly, the version. New versions of JQuery have not been released for some time and seem to not be in the making so its a safe bet to use their most recent versions as it has thousands of pages of help for its syntax and it's very stable. I would recommend anything in the 2.0 or higher series JQuery.

Comment: If i change the html to classes then the individual css styling will then apply to all the divs which i dont want. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: there is. nothing at all in your CSS is forcing you to chose styles according to anything other than what you want. So if I picked a test class that you current have in use like `.boxes` then just use your own class. If you want to select each div individually then use the id's I left on the div's. This is why I left them. Theres far too many reasons to usually want to select a wrapper class like a div, individually.